# Making a button invisible on a webpage until a certain event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web app I would like a page to have particular buttons hidden until certain events are triggered. I want "Save Changes" button to appear when "edit record" button has been clicked. How can I do this in JS or JQuery?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried..

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="edit" id="editbutton" onclick="showbutton()" />
<input type="button" value="Save changes" id="savebutton" />
```

You can use `JQuery('#editbutton').hide();`
in the `doccument.ready{}`function

You need a trigger function which will invoke on the edit button click.

Now this function will make the save changes button visible

```
function showbutton()
{
  JQuery('#savebutton').show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="b1" onclick="document.getElementById('b2').style.display='inline';">Edit Record</button>
<button id="b2" style="display:none;">Save Changes</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/74CxP/